# iOS Swift Twitter API call only works after it's made on Postman?

Tags: ios, swift, twitter-oauth, alamofire

I need to make twitter api call from my ios app. I first try it out on postman:

[image]

Then I click on the Generate Code on the top right corner and copy the header into ios swift project using alamofire to make the same exact api request (same user screen name, same count). And everything works fine.

[image]

However, if I just change the user screen name in the url in the ios project with same header, it no longer works. the response code is 401 Authentication credentials were missing or incorrect. Then if i go back to postman, change the user screen name in url and then make the api call, it works fine from postman, and it generates a new header with new oauth_nonce and new oauth_signature. Then if i copy the new header into the ios project, the api call with the new user screen name now works... is there way for me to skip the postman step and have it work just calling from ios?